# Upload files to server after pushing with GitLab CI

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I try to upload files automatically to a remote server with SSH after pushing to staging branch.

I have the folling GitLab CI command in my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  image: tetraweb/php:7.1
  before_script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    - ssh-add <(echo "$DD_PRIVATE_KEY")
    - apt-get install rsync
  script:
    - ssh -p22 ssh-xxxx@xxxxx.com "mkdir -p /website.com/_tmp"
    - rsync -rav -e ssh --exclude='.git/' --exclude='.gitlab-ci.yml' --delete-excluded ./ ssh-xxxx@xxxxx.com:/xxx.com/_tmp
    - ssh -p22 ssh-xxxx@xxxxx.com "mv /website.com/yyy/ /website.com/_old && mv /website.com/_tmp /website.com/yyy/"
    - ssh -p22 ssh-xxxx@xxxxx.com "rm -rf /website.com/_old"
  only:
    - staging
```

The GitLab Job says `Job succeeded`... but the files were not uploaded...in fact nothing happens.. but I get no error message or warnings...

[image]

Is there an error in my CI file?

**Edit for VonC**

I´ve added the right permissions and I´m using the -v flag now. The log looks like this: (I´ve replaced some informations)

```
$ ssh -v -p22 $HOST "mkdir -p $HOST:$ROOT/weburl/path/_tmp"
 OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u4, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
 debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
 debug1: /root/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
 debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
 debug1: Connecting to web-address.host.com [85.13.163.167] port 22.
 debug1: Connection established.
 debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
 debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u4
 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
 debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
 debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
 debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
 debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
 debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 43:89:10:22:d2:a6:54:f8:e0: .......
 Warning: Permanently added 'web-address.host.com,85.13.163.167' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
 debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
 debug1: Offering RSA public key: user@User-iMac.local
 debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 407
 debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
 Authenticated to web-address.host.com ([85.13.163.167]:22).
 debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
 debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
 debug1: Entering interactive session.
 debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
 debug1: Sending environment.
 debug1: Sending command: mkdir -p ssh-address.host.com:weburl/path/_tmp
 debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
 debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
 debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
 debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
 debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
 debug1: fd 2 clearing O_NONBLOCK
 Transferred: sent 3784, received 2560 bytes, in 0.4 seconds
 Bytes per second: sent 9472.1, received 6408.2
 debug1: Exit status 0
Running after_script
00:02
Saving cache
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:01
 Job succeeded
```

Comment: look at this [tutorial](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/examples/deployment/composer-npm-deploy.html#how-to-deploy-things). And note: .gitlab-ci.yml is a *YAML* file so you have to pay extra attention to indentation. Always use *spaces*, **not tabs**.

Comment: Thanks  the indentation is correct.. and the log shows me the last script lines.. but in green color. Seems like the lines were compiled as strings, not as ssh actions... 

Comment: "... and the log shows me the last script lines.." How do you mean this?

Comment: I´ve edited my topic with a screenshot of the log. The script runs and shows the ssh actions..

Comment: Whatever the script runs, have you tried manually running it once step by step to see if ti works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `image:` and `before_script:` sections means you are running your CI/CD jobs run inside a Docker container.

In that case, the "[SSH keys when using the Docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#ssh-keys-when-using-the-docker-executor)" paragraph mentions:

```
##
## Create the SSH directory and give it the right permissions
##
- mkdir -p ~/.ssh
- chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

I would test first if adding the right permission solves the issue.

And you need to make sure [your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` includes the target server own public key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#verifying-the-ssh-host-keys), as in [this script](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/ssh-private-key/-/blob/f3bbdb545ab795790b3a144bc280c02585c28b2e/.gitlab-ci.yml#L29-35) (but you chose `StrictHostKeyChecking  no` in your case).

I would also use an `ssh -v -p22 ...` in order to check if more details are printed when the ssh command is executed.

The SSH commands will looks for `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, which I don't see in your script (only `$DD_PRIVATE_KEY`). So double-check the output of an `ssh -v` to see what an `ssh` command is actually doing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I´ve edited my question with the current log file after adding your informations.

Comment: @asored From the look of it, it does connect with the SSH key `user@User-iMac.local` and does the mkdir: maybe the rync step makes somehow the rest of the script not executed? Try your same script without the rsync part, just for testing that the next ssh command is executed (even if it fails)

Comment: @VonC were u able to solve this issue, i am facing the same issue and its so wired.

Comment: @Krish I don't have solved more than what the answer describe. Which issue remains in your case?

Comment: even after adding the `.ssh/known_hosts` we are still missing files on the remote server from an MR/PR, but when I manually rerun the deploy step the files get moved into the remote server or if there is a new MR then the files on the target branch(older commit) get moved into the remote server, but the changes that are on the commit # of the MR/PR still doesn't appear on the remote server

Comment: @Krish OK, a separate question would be needed to investigate this one.